# Finding the inverse of a function at a point?

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f(x)= \frac{3}{\pi} x + \sin x, \ \frac{-\pi}{2}<x<\frac{\pi}{2}$. How to find out $f^{-1}(1)$?
The answer is $\frac{\pi}{6}.$

Comment: In my opinion,, just by guessing, knowing that $f$ is increasing on this interval. The only possible  guesses are rational multiples of $\pi$.

Comment: @Bernard There are a lot of rational multiples of $\pi$ between $0$ and $1/2$.  Guessing could take a while unless one has a methodology for iterating.

Comment: No so many that we can easily know the value of. Iterating will never yield $\pi/6$.

Comment: If iterating will never yield $\pi/6$, then how do you propose to proceed?  I am not trying to be antagonistic.  But I really don't think that "guessing" is the best way.

Comment: @Priya what type was this question; a multiple-choice or something different?

Comment: I'm with Bernard.  To make the guess "educated" rather than "wild".  Let $y=\frac 3\pi x$ and figure $y + \sin{\frac \pi 3 y} = 1$.  And note $y$ increases while $1-\sin{\frac \pi 3y}$ decreases so there is exactly one solution.  Going through the trig wheel solving $\sin{\frac {k\pi} {3n}} = \frac {n-k}n$ your *very* first guess will be $y=\frac 12$ but going through all "reasonable" $\frac kn$, the "easy ones" first, won't be hard. And you can hone in using the increasing, decreasing nature of the values.

Answer (score 1):

$$f(x)=3x/\pi+\sin x \implies x=f^{-1} (3x/\pi+\sin x) \implies \pi/6= f^{-1}(1/2+1/2)$$ $$\implies f^{-1}(1)=\pi/6.$$
One can get this result by finding the intersection of $y=\sin x$ and $y=1-3x/\pi$, see the graph below:

[image]

Comment: I'm interested, how would one solve $$\frac{3x}{\pi}+\sin(x)=1$$ if didn't know that $x=\pi/6$

Comment: You verified that $f^{-1}(1)=\frac\pi6$.   You did NOT propose a methodology.

Comment: It can be found numerically, graphically or just by inspection. These questions are usually set so that answer can come by hand by inspection.

Comment: Numerical solutions are approximations only.  And how does one find the exact solution graphically or "just by inspection?"  This post is an inadequate answer.

Comment: @MarkViola and Dr Zafar Ahmed, I think you both are right. I don't think the equation 
$$\frac{3x}{\pi}+\sin(x)=1$$ can be solved explicitly. Yet, if this question is sort of Multiple Choice question asking to find "*which of the following is $f'(1)$*", then the most appropriate way would be just verifying one of the options.

Comment: @VIVID And what if it isn't a multiple choice question?  Then, what would you propose?

Comment: @MarkViola If it was not, then just approximation would probably be all what I could propose.

Comment: @vivid, This question is actually given as a short answer type, not as a multiple choice. I think that, as someone pointed out above, this question may be set up in a view  that to find out by inspection or guessing with comon values.

Answer (score 1):

Nothing wrong with guessing.

Let $y = \frac 3\pi x$ then we have $y +\sin(\frac \pi 3y)=1$

We should have the basic fractions of $\pi$ memorized.   (as per this image [image] )

$0\le y =\sin(\frac \pi 3 y) < 1$.

Let $y=\frac kn$.  Then we have $\sin (\frac \pi 3 \frac kn) = \frac {n-k}n$.

our very first guess should be $y = \frac 12$ and $\sin \frac \pi 6$ does indeed equal $1- \frac 12$ so that is one solution.

And that's the only value as $1-\sin(\frac \pi 3y)$ is decreasing, while $y$ is increasing.

.

Now had we gone through the usual suspects and not gotten it, we could monkey with trig identities to calculate If we know the formula for $\sin (k\alpha) = $ some recursion formula of $\sin (\alpha)$ we can for $\frac 12 = \sin (\frac \pi 6) = \sin (\frac \pi 6*y*\frac 1y)=$ some recursion formula of $ \sin(\frac \pi 6y)$ and mucky guess till we get something.

Answer (score 1):

You could tentatively see what happens when you use the "small angle approximation" for $sin x$ which is simply $sin x=x$ provided $x$ is in radians.
$$f(x)=\frac{3}{\pi}x+sinx$$
is approximately,
$$f(x)=\frac{3}{\pi}x+x=x\left(\frac{3+\pi}{\pi}\right)$$
giving,
$$f^{-1}(x)=x\left(\frac{\pi}{3+\pi}\right)$$
$$f^{-1}(1)=\left(\frac{\pi}{3+\pi}\right)$$
This will throw you into the right sort of number region provided $x$ turns out to be small and so gives you a reason to try values like $\frac{\pi}{6}$ (although $\frac{\pi}{6}$ to only just small enough to be acceptable).

So not a "clean" method but quick to try and resulting in this case in the correct region to search further in.

Afterthought : The percentage error in using $x$ for $sinx$ when $x=\frac{\pi}{6}$ is 4.51%

Comment: this way of approximations will be very useful, in situations where there's no trial and error method with known values are applicable. Thanks